# Netbeans project 404 + apache localhost XAMPP

Tags: apache, netbeans, glassfish, localhost, http-status-code-404

I've created a web project in Netbeans. When I run it, it starts a glassfish server, and everything works fine (I don't understand why or how, but it works).

I also have XAMPP installed on my mac. I copied my netbeans project folder to my user sites folder, and ran my apache server with XAMPP.

I can access the sites index, but whenever I try to use a servlet, I get a 404, object not found.

Does this have something to do with glassfish web xml file? Servlet Mapping? Is there a new apache web xml file that I must create for it to work on apache server?

I can paste code if you need it.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache Server is for php based application and for running java based web project you have to install apache tomcat or glassfish as you have done previously where the servlet container is available.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I do have apache running using XAMPP. What do you mean "where the servlet container is available"?

Comment: Apache Server is not for Java based Web Application hosting. For java based web application hosting you need glassfish or apache tomcat, where a servlet container is there. In Apache server there is no servlet container, and so your application is not running. Apache Server is for hosting PHP based application

Comment: Oh I didn't realize Apache Tomcat was different than Apache. Thanks